# Converting some browser JavaScript to HTML and JavaScript files - Hashing using SHA256

Tags: javascript, html, hash, sha256, sha

I used https://youtu.be/w7UrV4-G798 to help hash some passwords from a website I am creating as a personal project. It uses JavaScript in the console to hash some text but I would like to use the code below as a function in my website, as a complete JavaScript beginner I can't seem to make it work. Here is the code:

```
const sha256script = document.createElement('script');
sha256script.src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-sha256/0.9.0/sha256.min.js'
document. head.appendChild(sha256script);
console.log(sha256('password'))
```

I currently have the password saved like this:

```
<!--Password-->
<div>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" type="password" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="new-password" minlength="8" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*" required>
</div>
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: just for the sake of better focusing the question: are you just asking how to set the value of the element having id="password" as the string returned from the function sha256?

Comment: Pretty much, but I would like to keep the code as simple and versatile as this hence the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo of how to set the value of the element having id as `password` with the hash coming from the call to `sha256().`

The function `sha256` here is just a fake placeholder. You will replace it with your own coming from the source you specified in your questoin.

The function `setPasswordValue()` accepts two arguments: the css selector to specify which element to assign its value and what's the value to set.

The element to assign the value to, is selected through `document.querySelector()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
> the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
> selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

And the value of the input element is set through its `value` property documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value

> The input control's value. When specified in the HTML, this is the
> initial value, and from then on it can be altered or retrieved at any
> time using JavaScript to access the respective HTMLInputElement
> object's value property. The value attribute is always optional,
> though should be considered mandatory for checkbox, radio, and hidden.

```js
function sha256(o){
  return "fakehash";
}

function setPasswordValue(selector, value){
  document.querySelector(selector).value = value;
}

function clickHandler(){
  setPasswordValue('#password', sha256('foo'))
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input
    id="password"
    name="password"
    type="password"
    spellcheck="false"
    autocomplete="new-password"ù
    minlength="8"
    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*"
    required>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="clickHandler();">Set Password Value</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, could you explain/comment the javascript to explain what it does, I can understand a bit it but have a few questions:
1. Why is there a o in the first line, 'sha256(o)'?
2. How does the second function work?
3. Why is there a # in front of the password in the clickHandler function?
4. Am I correct in understanding that the hashed password is saved as "fakehash", and if now what is it saved as?

Edit: just saw the edited answer, reading through it now

Comment: please don't take me wrong but your understanding is less than basic. I highly suggest you to give up with anything you are doing here and just learn the basics before you ever approach to do something real like this. You are asking what is a function, how css selectors work and what's the meaning of variables and returning values. The code I shared is VERY VERY simple. I grant you that in a few hours, if you start from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript you'll be able to understand that code easily

Comment: Will check it out right now, thank you for the help regardless!

Comment: by the way: 1. it means the function is called sha256 and accept one argument that will be referred as `o` later in the function body; 2. the 2nd function just selects the element in the dom and sets its value with what's returned from sha256; 3. because the css selector syntax, when using # it means: select element having that id; 4. the string `fakehash` is what's returned from my fake sha256 function and that will be used to set the value of the html element